# Why KeyError instead of ValueError in case of sets?

Tags: python, set

I have the following code :

```
set_a={1,2,3}
set_a.remove(4) # error here
```

It produces the following error message :

```
KeyError : 4
```

If I modify the code as

```
list_a=[1,2,3]
list_a.remove(4)
```

The output is

```
ValueError : list.remove(x) : x not in list
```

Why does the Python interpreter provides KeyError in the case of sets instead of ValueError as in the case of lists?

Keys are associated with dicts therefore are sets linked with dicts?

Or are set members called as keys? If so the reason for that please.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Set items are unique, so they are stored as keys and not just values like in a list.

Comment: @Aryerez What does "stored as keys" mean? In what way are the elements "keys"? The [KeyError documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError) even explicitly says "mapping (dictionary)", noting about sets. Sets aren't [mappings types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) but [set types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).

Comment: It is what it is. The documentation explicitly says that a `KeyError` will be raised. Whether it was a design mistake or a legitimate consideration is a moot point.

Comment: Element in a set is represented as a key, similar to a key in dictionary (as every key must be unique) because both these share same data structure called hash table. List has no such restrictions, so its simply an array.

Comment: I asked the same question to the [python forum][1] 

Kindly check there for further information ☺️

[1]:https://discuss.python.org/t/why-keyerror-instead-of-valueerror-in-the-case-of-sets/10224/7

Answer (score 0):

There are just different implementations: for [set remove function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/setobject.c#L1845) and for [list remove function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/listobject.c#L2602). They also have different structs under hood: [set](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Include/setobject.h#L42) and [list](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Include/cpython/listobject.h#L5).

As you can see there, set contains a table under the hood, list contains just array. So I believe it's the reason for this semantic.

Comment: But both set and list are mutable

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was a little worried and gone astray... :)

Comment: But all the Errors in Python has a particular reason, right? Then how can it explained with your answer? By the way, I can't downvote your answer :)))

Comment: Yes. But I've just provide you some technical details, where you can try to deduce the answer of the secret of the Python universe :)

Comment: Sorry in advance, that I can't explain it correctly. I'm not so smart yet

Comment: Well, this doesn't even attempt to answer the question, *why* the *set* chooses to give KeyError (rather than the more logical ValueError, as somewhat illustrated by the list example).

Comment: For my opinion, it's just personal choice of developers. One made one implementation for list, another one made other implementation for set :)

Comment: @ruslan_krivoshein, please understand that every error has a particular reason and that reason is conveyed in its name itself.

Comment: @12081, well I've dug a little and found the reason. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: Please check my comment under my question

Comment: @Kelly Bundy you too check my comment under my question

Comment: @12081 Looks like what I thought... someone ages ago made a bad decision and now it can't be changed anymore because existing code relies on it.

Comment: Looks almost as I discovered :)